# Metodos Iterator

Tags: java, arraylist

Como sumar todos los objetos de un arraylist con iterator:
esta parte me funciona correctamente

```
public class Uso_2cIterator {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      int num;
      Integer suma=0;
      int media;
      int cont=-1;

      ArrayList<Integer> miAdeNumeros=new ArrayList<>();

      do{
      System.out.print("Introduce nº enteros, para terminar escribe 0 (cero) " + "\nNumero: ");
      num=sc.nextInt();

      if(num!=0){
      miAdeNumeros.add(num); cont++;}
      }
      while(num!=0);


      System.out.println("Contenido del ArrayList " + miAdeNumeros);

      Iterator it=miAdeNumeros.iterator();
      while(it.hasNext()){
        //  System.out.print(" " +it.next() +" ");
```

El problema esta aqui no se que poner entre los parentesis para darle 1 posicion diferente cada vez, si fuese un bucle for le pondria i y listo pero no se como hacerlo con iterator

```
suma+=miAdeNumeros.get(0);
      }
       System.out.println("La suma total es: " +suma); 

       media=suma/miAdeNumeros.size();
       System.out.println("La media total es: " +media);

 }}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Para pulir un poco el concepto, se habla de objetos Iterator, el método .iterator() de una colección, devuelve un objeto Iterator, por lo que la duda la tienes sobre objetos Iterator, no métodos.
No obstante, creo darte la solución mas abajo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que usar el método next() del objeto iterator que defines como "it".

```
while(it.hasNext()){
 // tu código
 it.next();
}
```

Comment: era esto lo que me faltaba,ahora funciona correctamente, no entendia como colocar el it.next(); gracias

Comment: @bea marca esta respuesta como correcta si fue la que soluciono el problema

Answer (score 2):

No se entiende en que linea tenes el problema, pero vamos a solucionar tu problema de concepto.

Un bucle for, es un bucle iterador.

Eso es lo primero que tenes que entender.

Hacer un while, un do loop, un for, para todos los casos, es lo mismo. son bucles que iteran.

La unica diferencia que tienen entre ellos, es que en todos los casos, menos 1, el bucle se va a ejecutar de 0 a n veces (en el caso del do loop, se asegura que al menos se ejecuta una sola vez, asi que sera de 1 a n veces).

Entonces, practicamente, es hacer lo mismo siempre, aprovechando las ventajas que te da el lenguaje para no tener que escribir de mas. solamente eso.

Entonces, como ejemplo:

```
 for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Es lo mismo que

```
i = 0;
while (i < 5){
    ... el codigo...
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Buenas compañero, creo que el problema es que desconoce el uso de los objetos de tipo Iterator y no conoce el método Iterator.next(), no creo que lo que expones resuelva su duda.

Comment: Puede ser @RicardoFernandez. Si ese es el caso, tendremos que poner una respuesta que explique eso. Pero ojo porque lo que no sabe es como saber en que indice esta, no como ir al proximo elemento.

Comment: esta respuesta tambien me ha ayudado mucho ya que le he añadido la variable i en el while para usarlo como posicion pero la he iniciado con valor -1 ya que sino da error